# Javascript mouseover/mouseout animated button

Tags: javascript, button, animated

I have a button and onmouseover I want it to move right 100ish pixels at 10 pixels a move then stop. The moving isn't a problem its the stopping. I can do this no problem with jquery but I need to learn how to do it from scratch in javascript. this is my script to move right so far.

```
function rollRight() {      
    imgThumb.style.left = parseInt (imgThumb.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
    animate = setTimeout(rollRight,20);
}
```

That moves it right just fine so to stop it i tried taking the amount of loops 5x10=50px and wrote it again as

```
function rollRight() {
    var i=0;
    while (i < 5) {     
    imgThumb.style.left = parseInt (imgThumb.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
    animate = setTimeout(rollRight,20);
    i++;
    };
}
```

Now, I think I'm missing a piece to make it return the [] values for the while function, but I'm not sure how to make it work. Once I have the move right I can apply the same principle to move it back onmouseout.

If anyone can help me fix this that would be great. If you have a better script to do the animation that is just javascript, no libraries, that would be great too.

EDIT: Because leaving it as a comment didn't work well this is my current code

```
function rollRight() {   
    var left = parseInt (imgThumb.style.left);
    if(left < 50) { // or any other value   
    imgThumb.style.left = left + 10 + 'px';
    animate = setTimeout(rollRight,20);
    }
}

function revert() {   
    var left = parseInt (imgThumb.style.left);
    if(left < 50) { // or any other value   
    imgThumb.style.left = left + -10 + 'px';
    animate = setTimeout(rollRight,20);
    }
}
```

In the revert I'm having a problem getting it to move back. It's probably in the if(left<50) part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var animate = null;

function rollRight() { 
    if(animate) clearTimeout(animate);  
    var left = parseInt (imgThumb.style.left);
    if(left < 50) { // or any other value   
        imgThumb.style.left = left + 10 + 'px';
        animate = setTimeout(rollRight,20);
   }
}

function revert() {
    if(animate) clearTimeout(animate);
    var left = parseInt (imgThumb.style.left);
    if(left > 0) {
        imgThumb.style.left = (left - 10) + 'px';
        animate = setTimeout(revert,20); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Joseph and pckill's both work for going right but I'm having trouble with onmouseout revert back.

    function rollRight() {   
    var left = parseInt (imgThumb.style.left);
    if(left < 50) { // or any other value   
        imgThumb.style.left = left + 10 + 'px';
        animate = setTimeout(rollRight,20);
   }
}

function revert() {   
    var left = parseInt (imgThumb.style.left);
    if(left < 50) { // or any other value   
        imgThumb.style.left = left + -10 + 'px';
        animate = setTimeout(rollRight,20);
   }
}

wouldn't adding a negative value or subtracting move it back?

Comment: Yeah, it should, but you forgot to change the if statement. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You also forgot to change function name in `setTimeout`. I also added `clearTimeout` for the case that you want to start reverting when previous animation did not finish yet.

Comment: This works without the if(animate) but if you roll over it to many times it really fast it freaks out. If I leave in the if(animate) clearTimeout(animate); I get the error animate is not defined

Comment: I assumed you had this variable somewhere in your code.. You can fix it by adding it before the function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with setTimeout, you were close on your first one. I moved some hard coded numbers into variables:

```
var totalPixels = 100;
var increment = 10;
var frameTime = 20;
var numFrames = totalPixels / increment;
var curFrame = 0;

function rollRight() {      
    imgThumb.style.left = parseInt (imgThumb.style.left) + increment + 'px';

    if(curFrame++ < numFrames) {
        animate = setTimeout(rollRight,frameTime);
    }
}
```

You could also switch to use setInterval and then every time the interval fires, decide if you should stop the interval based on some incrementing value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var i = 0;
var moveInterval = setInterval(function(){
    if(i>=5) clearInterval(moveInterval);       
    rollRight();
    i++;
},20);

function rollRight() {      
    imgThumb.style.left = parseInt (imgThumb.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
}
```

Once it gets to 5, it will clear the interval out, and be done.